# Identify which code belongs to which group

Tags: r, algorithm, data.table

data

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c","c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g", "g","g"), code = c("G7", "G5", "G4", "K5", "H1", "H2", "K1", "H5", "J7", "K2", "HH", "K7", "JL","K5", "K7", "H5", "K5", "KO", "SS", "KK", "K2", "00", " 00", "J9" ))

code1 <- c("K2", "K1", "K5","K7")

code2 <- c("J2", "J1", "J5","J7","J9","JH","JP","JL","JJ","JL")
```

Desired output

```
      group code    indicator
 1:     a   G7         0
 2:     a   G5         0
 3:     a   G4         0
 4:     a   K5         0
 5:     b   H1         0
 6:     b   H2         0
 7:     b   K1         1
 8:     b   H5         0
 9:     b   J7         0
10:     c   K2         1
11:     c   HH         0
12:     c   K7         1
13:     c   JL         0
14:     c   K5         0
15:     d   K7         0
16:     d   H5         0
17:     e   K5         0
18:     e   KO         0
19:     f   SS         0
20:     f   KK         0
21:     g   K2         1
22:     g   00         0
23:     g   00         0
24:     g   J9         0
```

I'd love to have a solution in data.table, but other implementations are good too. I have a large data set. I would prefer to avoid for loops for speed consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired output. For example rows 4 and 7 both have a code in code1, bit in their groups (a and b) neither has a value from code2 present. Yet row 7 as 1 and row 3 has 0. The first code1 doens't appear till row 9.

Comment: row 7 precedes code "J7" within group b, which is part of code2.  I think you might have overlooked the grouping variable.

Comment: do you mean _Indicator should be coded as 1 when codes in code1 appear before any of the codes in code2 in a group. *before the next code1*_? or any subsequent code2 should be considered?

Comment: so basically any code1 within a group gets coded as 1 as long as it precedes code2 within a group.

Comment: why then for group C, K2 appears before any of the code2 data yet it has a 0?

Comment: Also still within group C,  J7 appears before any of the of the codes listed in code2 why does it have a 0?

Comment: mistake. corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
setDT(df)
df[, c("rn", "ind") := .(.I, 0L)]
df[code %chin% code1, ind := 
    df[code %chin% code2][.SD, on=.(group, rn>rn), mult="first", .N, by=.EACHI]$N
]
```

output (note that first row for group=c should also be a 1 since there is a JL after that)

```
    group code indicator rn ind
 1:     a   G7         0  1   0
 2:     a   G5         0  2   0
 3:     a   G4         0  3   0
 4:     a   K5         0  4   0
 5:     b   H1         0  5   0
 6:     b   H2         0  6   0
 7:     b   K1         1  7   1
 8:     b   H5         0  8   0
 9:     b   J7         0  9   0
10:     c   K2         0 10   1
11:     c   HH         0 11   0
12:     c   K7         1 12   1
13:     c   JL         0 13   0
14:     c   K5         0 14   0
15:     d   K7         0 15   0
16:     d   H5         0 16   0
17:     e   K5         0 17   0
18:     e   KO         0 18   0
19:     f   SS         0 19   0
20:     f   KK         0 20   0
21:     g   K2         1 21   1
22:     g   00         0 22   0
23:     g   00         0 23   0
24:     g   J9         0 24   0
    group code indicator rn ind
```

Comment: Error: x is type 'integer' (must be 'character' or NULL).  I'm getting this error. I wonder why.

Comment: which column in the dummy data is `x` in your actual data? in `data.table`, the data type for the column is important and you cannot just update a few elements in a column with a different data type

Comment: Funny thing, I don't have `x` anywhere.  I wonder where it came from.

Comment: which line is throwing the err?

Comment: Nvm, i forgot to set the original columns as character.

Comment: do you mind telling me what the last bit `$V1 ` is doing? I have no problem understanding the rest.

Comment: default naming of the column is using V*, so when you do not specify the output column name, it uses V*. I have updated it to using `.N` and output of `.N` uses N as column name as default. `$` extracts a column in a data.frame/data.table

Comment: Sorry, @chinsoon12, I thought I understood it. Can you explain how you did it.  I'm still a little fuzzy on  this bit: `ind :=  df[code %chin% code2][.SD, on=.(group, rn>rn), mult="first", .N, by=.EACHI]$N` Thanks.

Comment: Left join df where code are from code1 (I) with rows from df where code are from code2 (X) using group and where rows are below current row. Then use the first result if there are multiple join. For each row in I, get number of rows found (either 1 or 0) since we used mult=first

Answer (score 2):

One possible `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, indicator2 := nafill(
    as.integer(
        with(
            stack(list("1" = code1, "2" = code2)),
            ind[match(code, values)]
        )
    ),
    type = "nocb"
)][, indicator2 := nafill(c(diff(indicator2) == 1, 0),
    fill = 0
), group][]
```

gives

```
    group code indicator indicator2
 1:     a   G7         0          0
 2:     a   G5         0          0
 3:     a   G4         0          0
 4:     a   K5         0          0
 5:     b   H1         0          0
 6:     b   H2         0          0
 7:     b   K1         1          1
 8:     b   H5         0          0
 9:     b   J7         0          0
10:     c   K2         0          0
11:     c   HH         0          0
12:     c   K7         1          1
13:     c   JL         0          0
14:     c   K5         0          0
15:     d   K7         0          0
16:     d   H5         0          0
17:     e   K5         0          0
18:     e   KO         0          0
19:     f   SS         0          0
20:     f   KK         0          0
21:     g   K2         1          1
22:     g   00         0          0
23:     g   00         0          0
24:     g   J9         0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
df[, ind := code %in%code1 + 2 * code%in%code2, group][,
   ind := ind * (length(unique(ind)) == 3)][,
    indicator := (d<-cummax(ind)) * (d != 2) * ind * (d != 2), group][, ind:=NULL]

df
    group code indicator
 1:     a   G7         0
 2:     a   G5         0
 3:     a   G4         0
 4:     a   K5         1
 5:     b   H1         0
 6:     b   H2         0
 7:     b   K1         1
 8:     b   H5         0
 9:     b   J7         0
10:     c   K2         1
11:     c   HH         0
12:     c   K7         1
13:     c   JL         0
14:     c   K5         0
15:     d   K7         1
16:     d   H5         0
17:     e   K5         1
18:     e   KO         0
19:     f   SS         0
20:     f   KK         0
21:     g   K2         1
22:     g   00         0
23:     g   00         0
24:     g   J9         0
    group code indicator
```

OR

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(ind = code %in%code1 + 2 * code%in%code2,
         ind = ind * (length(unique(ind)) == 3),
         indicator = (d<-cummax(ind))*(d!=2) * ind*(ind!=2),
         ind = NULL)
```